# Junit runner with all bean mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'm actually on a Dropwizard project and I was asking to myself if it is possible to have a runner, which would by default mock all bean necessary to run the tested service. Instead of adding the @Mock on the Test class for each bean necessary, the runner make all of them mocked and when I need to override one of them (transform a mock to a spy) i can do it on the Test Class.

For example this code :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BuilderTest {

    @Mock
    private A a;

    @Spy
    private B b;

    @InjectMocks
    private C c;

}
```

Would become :

```
@RunWith(CustomMockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BuilderTest {

    @Spy
    private B b;

    @InjectMocks
    private C c;

}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  Why would you mock something you're not using?  If your component is using a ton of injectables and that makes it harder to test, then that's a signal to reduce the amount of injectables as opposed to try to wave something around with the tests (because the injectables are going to be easier to deal with in the long term).

Comment: You are right, unfortunately it is an old project and for now it is not possible to reduce the amount of injectabes, that's why i'm looking for a temporary solution like I described